# Common elements in two lists with duplicates

Tags: list, clojure, set-intersection

I want to find the common elements in two [lists, vectors, sequences] when there can be duplicates.

```
(common-elements [1] [1]) ; [1]
(common-elements [1 2] [1 1]) ; [1]
(common-elements [1 1] [1 1 1]) ; [1 1]
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
(defn remove-first [elem coll]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [s (seq coll)]
      (let [f (first s), r (rest s)]
        (if (= elem f) 
          r 
          (cons f (remove-first elem r)))))))

(defn common-elements [coll1 coll2]
  (lazy-seq
    (when (and (seq coll1) (seq coll2))
      (let [f (first coll1)]
        (if (some #{f} coll2)
          (cons f (common-elements (rest coll1)
                                   (remove-first f coll2)))
          (common-elements (rest coll1) coll2)))))
```

My experience with [4clojure](http://www.4clojure.com/) has shown me that I rarely write the most idiomatic or succinct code so I'm interested in finding out whether there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: To clarify: your input data structures should be treated as multisets? (Elements may appear more than once but their order doesn't matter?)

Comment: Correct, I'm not interested in ordering, just content. In my current implementation, common elements are ordered as they are ordered in coll1, but that is arbitrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my implementation. It uses maps and sets to hold intermediate data, and thus is not lazy like your version, but I think it is more readable and will have better overall performance characteristics (your version has quadratic time complexity to realize the results from common-elements).

```
(require '[clojure.set :as set])
(defn common-elements [& colls]
  (let [freqs (map frequencies colls)]
    (mapcat (fn [e] (repeat (apply min (map #(% e) freqs)) e))
            (apply set/intersection (map (comp set keys) freqs)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Not the most efficient, but fairly concise:

```
(defn common [& ss] 
  (let [fs (map frequencies ss), ks (map set ss)]
    (select-keys (apply merge-with min fs) 
                 (reduce clojure.set/intersection ks))))
```

Returns maps of values and counts

```
(common [1] [1]) ;=> {1 1}
(common [1 2] [1 1]) ;=> {1 1}
(common [1 1] [1 1 1]) ;=> {1 2}
```

Another approach, modified from my own question [Idiomatic/Efficient Clojure way to intersect two a priori sorted vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160830/idiomatic-efficient-clojure-way-to-intersect-two-a-priori-sorted-vectors),

```
(defn common [x y] 
  (loop [x (sort x) y (sort y) acc []] 
    (if (and x y)
      (let [x1 (first x) 
            y1 (first y)] 
      (cond 
        ( < x1 y1) (recur (next x) y acc) 
        ( > x1 y1) (recur x (next y) acc) 
        :else (recur (next x) (next y) (conj acc x1))))
    acc)))
```

which returns a vector as in the original question

```
(common [1 1 1 2 2 3] [1 1 2 5]) ;=> [1 1 2]
```

Of course if you know your inputs are sorted, you may omit the `sort`, and if you furthermore know they are vectors you can use the optimizations provided by amalloy in answer to the referenced question.

Comment: This function as written doesn't restrict keys in the result to only those common between the collections.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I was trying to golf and pasted the wrong version. Edited to correct.

Comment: The second function you listed is actually the fastest of the bunch, at least on sequences ~20-50 elements long. However it would need an additional comparator parameter if the elements aren't intrinsically comparable.

Comment: Will not work if list contains negative integers, correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn get-commons [l1 l2]
  (let [f1 (frequencies l1) 
        f2 (frequencies l2)
        common (clojure.set/intersection (set l1) (set l2))
        love (merge-with (fn [val1 val2] (min val1 val2)) f1 f2)] 
    (mapcat #(repeat (love %) %) common)))
```

The function is similar to the ones given in previous answers. I still submit this answer for Clojure beginners who may stumble on this question. I believe the function makes clearer the steps needed for the function to evaluate to a result.